# - (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

How to use this method

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines
```

I have read the document of apple but i can not understand it any more, i do the test : i override this method, and only `NSLog` something in it, but i found it not called automatic , the apple document said that this method must not call directly, so if i don't call this method myself, who will call it.

Can you tell me how to use this method and which method will call it in the original apple method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the method which needs to be overridden in the subclass. This method will get called directly and you should not call it.

However there should be a function call for methods `sizeToFit or sizeThatFits` to get this method called. If you will not call the method `sizeToFit`, it will not get called.

In this method you can return the bounds of a label before doing any other tasks. It will return original bounds if you will not do any modifications.

Comment: If it helped, you can upvote or accept the answer by clicking on aerrow sign.

Comment: thanks,i have try what you have said,it's right.And it is puzzled for me (sorry,my English is poor,maybe there are some mistakes in grammar)to understand it clearly. Is that right to think that if i don't call the method sizeToFit or sizeThatFits ,I will be able to call this method by myself? is that right?

Comment: No..you should not call it directly.it will get call only if you make the call for sizeToFit or sizethatFits.

Comment: Actually,i want to program a label by myself to make it can use different attribute such as font,color and it can find out the phone number ,the link and so on.So i must do the typesetter by myself,i want to know if i can call this method 'textRectForBounds: limitedToNumberOfLines' by myself when i program my label . now i think i can override it and call it in my private method.Do you think so?

Comment: If you want to eliminate sizeToFit call then you can call it. There is no harm in calling it. The fact is that its not advisable.

Comment: Actually,i want to program a label by myself to make it can use different attribute such as font,color and it can find out the phone number ,the link and so on.So i must do the typesetter by myself,i want to know if i can call this method 'textRectForBounds: limitedToNumberOfLines' by myself when i program my label . now i think i can override it and call it in my private method.Do you think so?

Comment: Use the attributedText property for that.